# Why do my field-set containers overflow at mobile-view, but not at larger screen sizes?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, fieldset

I'm creating a mobile-first responsive website using forms. This is the desired mockup I need to create after 769px. https://ibb.co/LQ0Gwt7. Here is the desired mockup for 769px and below: https://ibb.co/7tbDShb
But why is that before 769px, the contents of my fieldset containers spill out?Whats causing this to happen? I put red borders around certain elements for clarity sake.
Take a look here: https://ibb.co/1J9n8pW

Here`s my CSS and HTML code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: seashell;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}

.header-content {
  text-align: center;
  background: #29405a;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #29405a;
}

.signup {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px #29405a dashed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}

.form {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 70%;
  background: #feffff;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px red solid;
}

.field {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 3px red solid;
}


/*input styles*/

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"],
textarea,
select {
  background: #e8eeef;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 12px 0;
}

button[type="submit"] {
  background: #52bab3;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.news-input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.news-input label {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.contact-input {
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px red solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.label {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.textarea {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.extra-info {
  text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .contact-input {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .label,
  .input {
    flex: 1;
  }
  .input {
    flex: 3;
  }
  .zip-input,
  .zip-label {
    flex: 0;
    flex-basis: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8' />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Registration Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="header-content">
      <h1>The Code Review</h1>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="signup">
    <h2>Sign up for our newsletter</h2>
    <p>Get the latest news on how your code is doing right in your inbox</p>
  </div>

  <form action="index.html" get="post" class="form">

    <fieldset class="field">
      <legend>Contact Information</legend>

      <div class="contact-input">
        <label class="label" for="name">Name</label>
        <input class="input" type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
      </div>

      <div class="contact-input">
        <label class="label" for="mail">Email Address</label>
        <input class="input" type="email" id="mail" name="user_email">
      </div>

      <div class="contact-input">
        <label class="label" for="phone-number">Phone Number</label>
        <input class="input" type="tel" id="phone-number" name="user_phone">
      </div>

      <div class="contact-input">
        <label class="label" for="street">Street Address</label>
        <input class="input" type="text" id="street" name="user_street">
      </div>

      <div class="contact-input">
        <label class="label" for="city">City</label>
        <input class="input" type="text" id="city" name="user_city">
      </div>

      <div class="contact-input">
        <label class="label" for="state">State</label>
        <select class="input" id="state" name="user_state">
          <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
          <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
          <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
          <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
          <option value="CA">California</option>
          <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
          <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
          <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
          <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
          <option value="FL">Florida</option>
          <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
          <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
          <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
          <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
          <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
          <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
          <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
          <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
          <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
          <option value="ME">Maine</option>
          <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
          <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
          <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
          <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
          <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
          <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
          <option value="MT">Montana</option>
          <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
          <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
          <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
          <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
          <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
          <option value="NY">New York</option>
          <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
          <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
          <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
          <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
          <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
          <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
          <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
          <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
          <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
          <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
          <option value="TX">Texas</option>
          <option value="UT">Utah</option>
          <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
          <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
          <option value="WA">Washington</option>
          <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
          <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
          <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="contact-input zip">
        <label class="label zip-label" for="zip">Zip Code</label>
        <input class="input zip-input" type="text" id="zip" name="user_zipcode">
      </div>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="field">
      <legend>Newsletter</legend>

      <p>Select the newspaper you'd like to recieve:</p>

      <div class="news-input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="html-news" name="user_htm-news" checked></input>
        <label for="html-news">HTML News</label>
      </div>

      <div class="news-input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="css-news" name="user_css-news">
        <label for="css-news">CSS News</label>
      </div>

      <div class="news-input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="javascript-news" name="user_javascript-news">
        <label for="javascript-news">Javascript News</label>
      </div>

      <p>Newsletter Format</p>

      <div class="news-input">
        <input type="radio" id="html" name="user_newsletter-format" checked>
        <label for="html">HTML</label>
      </div>

      <div class="news-input">
        <input type="radio" id="css-news" name="user_newsletter-format">
        <label for="css-news">CSS News</label>
      </div>

      <p>Other topics you'd like to hear about</p>
      <div class="textarea">
        <textarea id="topics" name="user_topics"></textarea>
      </div>

    </fieldset>

    <div class="button">
      <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </div>

    <div class="extra-info">
      <p>Copyright the Code Review</p>
    </div>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

On small screens you have to set

```
.form {
   width: 100%;
}
```

otherwise the bigger components will overflow your too small `.form` div.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: seashell;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}

.header-content {
  text-align: center;
  background: #29405a;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid #29405a;
}

.signup {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 2px #29405a dashed;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}

.form {
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 100%; /* SET TO 100% */
  background: #feffff;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px red solid;
}

.field {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 3px red solid;
}


/*input styles*/

input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"],
textarea,
select {
  background: #e8eeef;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 12px 0;
}

button[type="submit"] {
  background: #52bab3;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.news-input {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.news-input label {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.contact-input {
  margin: 20px auto;
  border: 1px red solid;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.label {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.textarea {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.button {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.extra-info {
  text-align: center;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {

  .form{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .contact-input {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  .label,
  .input {
    flex: 1;
  }
  .input {
    flex: 3;
  }
  .zip-input,
  .zip-label {
    flex: 0;
    flex-basis: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8' />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Registration Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div class="header-content">
      <h1>The Code Review</h1>
    </div>
  </header>

  <div class="signup">
    <h2>Sign up for our newsletter</h2>
    <p>Get the latest news on how your code is doing right in your inbox</p>
  </div>

  <form action="index.html" get="post" class="form form_setter">

    <fieldset class="field">
      <legend>Contact Information</legend>

      <div class="contact-input">
        <label class="label" for="name">Name</label>
        <input class="input" type="text" id="name" name="user_name">
      </div>

      <div class="contact-input">
        <label class="label" for="mail">Email Address</label>
        <input class="input" type="email" id="mail" name="user_email">
      </div>

      <div class="contact-input">
        <label class="label" for="phone-number">Phone Number</label>
        <input class="input" type="tel" id="phone-number" name="user_phone">
      </div>

      <div class="contact-input">
        <label class="label" for="street">Street Address</label>
        <input class="input" type="text" id="street" name="user_street">
      </div>

      <div class="contact-input">
        <label class="label" for="city">City</label>
        <input class="input" type="text" id="city" name="user_city">
      </div>

      <div class="contact-input">
        <label class="label" for="state">State</label>
        <select class="input" id="state" name="user_state">
          <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
          <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
          <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
          <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
          <option value="CA">California</option>
          <option value="CO">Colorado</option>
          <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
          <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
          <option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option>
          <option value="FL">Florida</option>
          <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
          <option value="HI">Hawaii</option>
          <option value="ID">Idaho</option>
          <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
          <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
          <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
          <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
          <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
          <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
          <option value="ME">Maine</option>
          <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
          <option value="MA">Massachusetts</option>
          <option value="MI">Michigan</option>
          <option value="MN">Minnesota</option>
          <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
          <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
          <option value="MT">Montana</option>
          <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
          <option value="NV">Nevada</option>
          <option value="NH">New Hampshire</option>
          <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
          <option value="NM">New Mexico</option>
          <option value="NY">New York</option>
          <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
          <option value="ND">North Dakota</option>
          <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
          <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
          <option value="OR">Oregon</option>
          <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
          <option value="RI">Rhode Island</option>
          <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
          <option value="SD">South Dakota</option>
          <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
          <option value="TX">Texas</option>
          <option value="UT">Utah</option>
          <option value="VT">Vermont</option>
          <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
          <option value="WA">Washington</option>
          <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
          <option value="WI">Wisconsin</option>
          <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="contact-input zip">
        <label class="label zip-label" for="zip">Zip Code</label>
        <input class="input zip-input" type="text" id="zip" name="user_zipcode">
      </div>

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="field">
      <legend>Newsletter</legend>

      <p>Select the newspaper you'd like to recieve:</p>

      <div class="news-input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="html-news" name="user_htm-news" checked></input>
        <label for="html-news">HTML News</label>
      </div>

      <div class="news-input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="css-news" name="user_css-news">
        <label for="css-news">CSS News</label>
      </div>

      <div class="news-input">
        <input type="checkbox" id="javascript-news" name="user_javascript-news">
        <label for="javascript-news">Javascript News</label>
      </div>

      <p>Newsletter Format</p>

      <div class="news-input">
        <input type="radio" id="html" name="user_newsletter-format" checked>
        <label for="html">HTML</label>
      </div>

      <div class="news-input">
        <input type="radio" id="css-news" name="user_newsletter-format">
        <label for="css-news">CSS News</label>
      </div>

      <p>Other topics you'd like to hear about</p>
      <div class="textarea">
        <textarea id="topics" name="user_topics"></textarea>
      </div>

    </fieldset>

    <div class="button">
      <button type="submit">Sign Up</button>
    </div>

    <div class="extra-info">
      <p>Copyright the Code Review</p>
    </div>

  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Form inputs have a [default width that the user agent (browser) applies](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-html53-20181018/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-input-size) unless you override it.

> The size IDL attribute is limited to only non-negative numbers greater than zero and has a default value of 20.

The container for your form inputs is 70% the width of the viewport, once the viewport is small enough, 70% becomes less than the default width of the form inputs. Thus the overflow.

At larger viewport sizes you're using flexbox properties which causes the inputs to stretch a particular width of their containing element.

Apply `width: 100%;` to your form inputs.

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"],
textarea,
select {
  width: 100%;
  background: #e8eeef;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03) inset;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 12px 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This would be your best approach, no need for media query:

```
.form {
   width: 100%;
   display: block;
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   max-width: 1024px; //insert your prefer value here;
}
```

Comment: @hungerstar did you try my solution ? The op's question was clear but his trouble comes from the `form` CSS selector, not with the field. He set the form 70% but forgot to reset this value back to 100% in mobile, no wonder that causes the overflow issue. My solution is a quick and works on all browser device width, and would be considered more advance to some one.

Comment: It still overflows, just not as soon as it used to. The issue revolves around the default size that the user agent (browser) is defining for an `input`. Also, block level elements like `form` do not require `width: 100%` or `display: block` (unless you're resetting them due to media query/other) as that's their default. Adding a `max-width` and `auto` to the left/right margins is a patter for centering a block element.

Comment: I'm still wondering did you check on his design intention ? Clearly on desktop he wants the form to be centered, not full 100%. I do know on block-level element there' no need for `display: block` and `width: 100%`, but I still believe this would help for someone like him. This simply helps him understand more about CSS, not just some magical stuff. If you're just set `width:100%` without using max-width or put it in a mobile media query, your solution will not work as his expected.

Comment: I've seen all the screenshots and understand the OPs intention. Block elements and their default formatting (layout implementation) is not _"some magical stuff."_ It's fundamental to being a competent web developer. Demonstrating unnecessary CSS properties hinder a beginners ability to understand fundamental concepts because they'll believe those things are necessary when they are not. As for `width: 100%`, I'm referring to form elements, i.e. `inputs`, `select` etc. and the container element for the form elements.